# Error in postfix

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dpkg, email, postfix

I am attempting to run `sudo apt-get install -f` however it seems that the `postfix` package is broken:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
[sudo] password for learner: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up postfix (2.11.0-1ubuntu1) ...
update-rc.d: /etc/init.d/postfix: file does not exist
dpkg: error processing package postfix (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postfix
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

However I do not receive an output from:

```
sudo dkpg --configure -a
```

I am also getting this error:

```
$ sudo service postfix status
[sudo] password for learner:
postfix: unrecognized service
```

Results for `sudo apt-get purge(or autoremove) postfix:`

```
learner@juggernaut:~$ sudo apt-get purge postfix
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  lsb-invalid-mta
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  postfix*
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  lsb-invalid-mta
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/5,106 B of archives.
After this operation, 3,541 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: postfix: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 lsb-core depends on lsb-invalid-mta (>= 4.1+Debian11ubuntu6) | mail-transport-agent; however:
  Package lsb-invalid-mta is not installed.
  Package mail-transport-agent is not installed.
  Package postfix which provides mail-transport-agent is to be removed.

(Reading database ... 228875 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing postfix (2.11.0-1ubuntu1) ...
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/postfix not found.
dpkg: error processing package postfix (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 100
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postfix
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
learner@juggernaut:~$
```

Comment: `sudo touch /etc/init.d/postfix; sudo apt-get purge postfix `

Comment: Or if using `systemd` create a phony systemd service file: https://scottlinux.com/2014/12/08/how-to-create-a-systemd-service-in-linux-centos-7/ I set `ExecStart` to `/bin/true` although it looks like this doesn't apply to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

@A.B 's comment fixed my issue, bumping to an answer:

```bsh
sudo touch /etc/init.d/postfix; sudo apt-get purge postfix
```

Answer (score -2):

You are successfully running `apt-get install -f` and it is informing you that:

> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
>   1 not fully installed or removed.

So, it would appear that there are two valuable pieces of information to be had here; The first is that 15 of your currently installed packages can be upgraded; secondly, that you have one package that is not correctly or fully installed; Which is apparently postfix.

First things first you should update your packages ...

```
sudo apt-get update
```

followed by:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -u
```

Perhaps now you will be able to configure postfix having fixed any dependency issues...

Comment: i have tried all of this...

Comment: Personally, I thought you post a little strange; why are you combining both dpkg and apt-get in your package installation? You don't actually ask a question here; So  What is your reason for posting this?

Comment: Did you try a reinstall?